# Using Gevent with blocking code

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask, gevent

I am building a website having push events and as such requires Gevent websockets to work, but the rest of the code is blocking as I really don't know how I would make it async.

Because of this, is there some problem in using Gevent with blocking code?
I'm using **monkey** **patch_all** and starting the server like this, coupled with a nginx proxy pass to hide the port number:

```
WSGIServer(('127.0.0.1', 8000), app).serve_forever()
```

If I did understand good, doing all of this will ensure that blocking code flow will be made cooperative through Greenlets?

Like I have this simple code (a route definition of the homepage) which fetches all the items from **posts** collection, save it in **database** var and feeds to **render_template** (index.html) as **db** that then will be looped afterwards:

```
# front page
def index():
    database = posts.find()
    return render_template('index.html', db=database)
```

This is the index.html actually:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}


  <div class=post>

  {% for post in db %}

      <h4><a href="/post/{{ post._id }}/{{ post.slug }}"> {{ post.title }} </a></h4>

  {% endfor %}

  </div>


{% endblock %}
```

Is this code safe to use with Gevent or should I rely on something else maybe?

If not what should I do to make it async? fragment the loop? "asynchronize" database calls such as **posts.find()**?

Comment: It seems like you're on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

If `monkey patch_all` is one of the first modules imported by your project your code will run cooperative. Monkey patch replaces many blocking build in python modules with non blocking gevent versions which behave in the same way but non blocking.

So if your database/webserver is using normal tcp connections or if you are using the 'green' version of your database driver you don't have to do anything and things will just work coopertively.

[gevent tutorial](http://sdiehl.github.io/gevent-tutorial/)